# Is there an IdentityHashMap implementation that maintains insert order?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, guava

I need a HashMap that 
(1) matches keys by Object reference, and
(2) maintains insertion order when iterating

These functionalities are implemented in IdentityHashMap and LinkedHashMap separately.

Is there any way to get a data structure that suits my need? Either one that is present in Java standard OR 3rd party libraries (like Guava), OR by using some trick on LinkedHashMap maybe, so that it uses object reference for matching keys?

Comment: Why do you need identity comparison? That's highly unusual all by itself.

Comment: I'm trying to maintain an object-to-object mapping for classes from third-party libraries. It's for a complex algorithm I'm developing rather than simple procedural code, and having this mapping speeds up the processing.

Comment: These classes override `equals`?

Comment: Hmm... I didn't check that. Although of course, it my be overriden in future versions of the library. I dont want to assume anything that is out of my hands - this is production code.

Comment: I'm currently thinking of making some sort of a Wrapper class for the Key object class that overrides equals to mean object reference equality. Then I could probably use a LinkedHashMap, and get the property of IdentityHashMap.

Comment: But then if I'm wrapping the class anyway, I could just hold the Value in the Wrapper object and maintain a list of the Wrapper objects... it's a quandary. I'll probably think more and go with the one that makes the code easier to read, unless I get some better answers here.

Comment: Do you need the map to support the `remove` operation?

Comment: no, i can do without it. just need to add objects, use as an index, and throw away.

Comment: I think this is too obscure to make it worth writing a new implementation of map for this. I think you could just use a `LinkedHashMap` where you use a wrapper class for the keys as you suggested. This solution bothers me slightly as it consumes a huge amount of memory (all keys have to be wrapped, all entries need a separate `Map.Entry` object, a `LinkedHashMap` is a doubly-linked list, whereas you only need a singly-linked list).

Comment: True. But I'm pressed for time, and trying to focus on my algorithm rather than the data structure nitty-gritties. I don't think the memory will be THAT bad since it will just be storing references.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/hypergraphdb/source/browse/trunk/core/src/java/org/hypergraphdb/util/LinkedIdentityHashMap.java?r=1181

Comment: Wow! Looks like someone did need it before me. Thanks Paul! Although it will be *VERY* weird to include HyperGraphDB just for this; hopefully the class is isolated and I can just use it in my code. Will look into it...

Answer (score 5):

You can use Guava's [`Equivalence`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/23.0/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) for this:

```
Equivalence<Object> equivalence = Equivalence.identity();
Map<Equivalence.Wrapper<Object>, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(equivalence.wrap(a), b);
```

Comment: I could in a pinch, but that code is definitely not easy on the eyes... Thanks, though - learnt one new thing about Guava!

Comment: @NK You could certainly make it prettier by making your own `Map` implementation that delegates to this one.  Also I was using more wrappers than necessary, fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

It interested me, so I wrote an implementation.

```
public class IdentityLinkedHashMap<K, T>  extends AbstractMap<K,T> {

    static Equivalence<Object> equivalence = Equivalence.identity();

    private IdentityLinkedHashSet set = new IdentityLinkedHashSet();

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, T>> entrySet() {
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public T put(K k, T t) {
        return set.innerMap.put( equivalence.wrap(k), t);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object arg0) {
        return set.contains(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(Object arg0) {
        return set.innerMap.remove(equivalence.wrap(arg0));
    }


    @Override
    public T get(Object arg0) {
        return set.innerMap.get(equivalence.wrap(arg0));
    }


    public class MyEntry implements Entry<K, T> {

        final Entry<Equivalence.Wrapper<K>, T> entry;

        public MyEntry(Entry<Wrapper<K>, T> entry) {
            this.entry = entry;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return entry.getKey().get();
        }

        @Override
        public T getValue() {
            return entry.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public T setValue(T value) {
            return entry.setValue(value);
        }

    }


    public class IdentityLinkedHashSet extends AbstractSet<Entry<K,T>> {

        Map<Equivalence.Wrapper<K>, T> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        @Override
        public Iterator<Entry<K, T>> iterator() {
            return Iterators.transform(innerMap.entrySet().iterator(), entry -> new MyEntry(entry));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(Entry<K, T> entry) {
            Wrapper<K> wrap = equivalence.wrap(entry.getKey());
            innerMap.put(wrap, entry.getValue());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return innerMap.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object arg0) {
            return innerMap.containsKey(equivalence.wrap(arg0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: great piece of code you got here! Thank you for posting it. It worked for me and my testing.